# how to append data to address fields when array of address is there for one name using angular12

Tags: javascript, angular, append

i have a json object, i have to append the data in below format
from object1, i need `profileName + address1[0] + city[0] + state + zip[0]` if there is address2 array as well, then it should be `profileName + address2[0] + city[0] + state + zip[0]`
same way for 3 and 4 if there is no empty array. so likewise all the address present under one profile name must comes as individual rows
Expected output:
if there are array of strings in AddressLine1, AddressLine2, AddressLine3, AddressLine4, and respectively City and zip will have array of states and zips.
so i must get data like

```
profileName + address1[0] + city[0] + state + zip[0]
.
.
profileName + address1[5] + city[5] + state + zip[5]
profileName + address2[0] + city[0] + state + zip[0]
.
.
profileName + address2[5] + city[5] + state + zip[5] and so on
```

TS:

```
 for (var item in results.hits) {
            let dataValue = {name:'',address:''}
            dataValue.name = results.hits[item]._source.ProfileName;
            dataValue.address = results.hits[item]._source.Address + ' '+ results.hits[item]._source.City+ ' ' + results.hits[item]._source.State + ' ' + results.hits[item]._source.Zip;
            data.push(dataValue);
          }
```

i have done ts in below format, but not able to append address, city and zip

```
  {
      "hits": {
        "hits": [
          {
            "_source": {
              "ProfileName": "",
              "AddressLine1": [
                "7508 abc 105",
                "7400 def, Suite 200",
                "727 xyz",
                "8001 123",
                "1650 ngr",
              ],
              "AddressLine2": [
              "11333 East ",
                "2308 North ",
                "8831 East ",
                "204 dsj",
                "1517 HWY "
            ],
              "AddressLine3": [],
              "AddressLine4": [],
              "Zip": [
                "116-900",
                "749-01",
                "77-52",
                "179",
                "702",
                "746",
                "7402",
                "74-5801",
                "741",
                "7342"
              ],
              "City": [
                "OKLAHOMA CITY",
                "Oklahoma City",
                "OKLAHOMA CITY",
                "OKLAHOMA CITY",
                "Broken Arrow",
                "Tulsa",
                "BROKEN ARROW",
                "TULSA",
                "PRYOR",
                "GUYMON"
              ],
              "State": "OK",
              "LicenseType": "Wholesale Distributor",
              "BusinessModel": "Wholesaler",
              "LicenseNumber": [
                "1-W-1",
                "1-W-5",
                "1-W-6",
                "1-W-82",
                "2-W-12",
                "2-W-45",
                "2-W-416",
                "2-W-91",
                "30-W-21",
                "43-W-95"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "_source": {
              "ProfileName": "HEALTHCARE ",
              "AddressLine1": [
                "110 Rsahasd"
              ],
              "AddressLine2": [
                "220 road"
              ],
              "AddressLine3": [],
              "AddressLine4": [],
              "Zip": [
                "73075"
              ],
              "City": [
                "PAULS VALLEY"
              ],
              "State": "OK",
              "LicenseType": "Retail",
              "BusinessModel": "Dispenser",
              "LicenseNumber": [
                "2-667"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "_index": "pulse",
            "_id": "19297",
            "_score": 5.054507,
            "_source": {
              "ProfileName": "PHARMACY",
              "AddressLine1": [
                "101 West MAIN",
                "101 East MAIN"
              ],
              "AddressLine2": [],
              "AddressLine3": [],
              "AddressLine4": [],
              "Zip": [
                "749",
                "739"
              ],
              "City": [
                "JOHN",
                "JON"
              ],
              "State": "OK",
              "LicenseType": "Retail",
              "BusinessModel": "Dispenser",
              "LicenseNumber": [
                "1-89",
                "1-39"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "_index": "pulse",
            "_id": "22739",
            "_score": 5.054507,
            "_source": {
              "ProfileName": "THE MEDICINE ",
              "AddressLine1": [
                "311 N WASHINGTON AVENUE",
                "311 N WASHINGTON AVENUE"
              ],
              "AddressLine2": [],
              "AddressLine3": [],
              "AddressLine4": [],
              "Zip": [
                "74701-3641",
                "74701-3641"
              ],
              "City": [
                "DURANT",
                "DURANT"
              ],
              "State": "OK",
              "LicenseType": "Retail",
              "BusinessModel": "Dispenser",
              "LicenseNumber": [
                "27-4393",
                "27-8581"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "_index": "pulse",
            "_id": "27256",
            "_score": 5.054507,
            "_source": {
              "ProfileName": "WAL-MART ",
              "AddressLine1": [
                "7520 East ",
                "772 North",
                "2705 West",
                "1018 N ",
                "3571 W ",
                "2551 CLASS",
                "13503 S ",
                "3651 CLASS",
                "3301 SW 104",
                "4545 W 6TH"
              ],
              "AddressLine2": [
              "6437 North",
                "14185 drive",
                "4900 Sooner",
                "2001 SST",
                "2019 EST",
                "10938 SDR",
                "12200 SWACO",
                "12912 E N",
                "3900 EHILLDR",
                "3139 SE",
                ],
              "AddressLine3": [],
              "AddressLine4": [],
              "Zip": [
                "63110",
                "63132",
                "63020",
                "63135",
                "63018",
                "64137",
                "64133",
                "64033",
                "64055",
                "64014",
              ],
              "City": [
                "MIDWEST CITY",
                "WARR ACRES",
                "CHOCTAW",
                "OKLAHOMA CITY",
                "CHICKASHA",
                "TULSA",
                "TULSA",
                "GLENPOOL",
                "OWASSO",
                "BROKEN ARROW",
              ],
              "State": "OK",
              "LicenseType": "Retail",
              "BusinessModel": "Dispenser",
              "LicenseNumber": [
                "1-5770",
                "1-6379",
                "1-6621",
                "1-6934",
                "18-5060",
                "2-3864",
                "2-5116",
                "2-5298",
                "2-5444",
                "2-5449",
                "2-6632",
                "26-6921",
                "2-6710",
                "2-7368",
                "2-7447",
                "29-3720",
                "30-6922",
                "34-4508",
                "35-5557",
                "3-6891",
                "46-5049",
                "52-5782",
                "55-5459",
                "5-6935",
                "7-6284",
                "7-6951",
                "7-7474",
                "7-7573",
                "7-7692",
                "8-5133"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

new Json:

```
 result= {
      "hits": [
        {
          "_index": "pulse",
          "_id": "17320",
          "_score": 12.9226,
          "_source": {
            "ProfileName": "Pharmarx Pharmaceutical Inc",
            "State": "CA",
            "BusinessModel": "Dispenser",
            "LicenseInfo": [
              {
                "LicenseType": "Resident Licensed Sterile Compounding",
                "LicenseNumber": "99658",
                "AddressLine1": "21441 Osborne St Ste C & D",
                "AddressLine2": "",
                "AddressLine3": "",
                "AddressLine4": "",
                "Zip": "91304",
                "City": "Canoga Park"
              },
              {
                "LicenseType": "Retail Pharmacy",
                "LicenseNumber": "50511",
                "AddressLine1": "21441 Osborne St Ste C & D",
                "AddressLine2": "",
                "AddressLine3": "",
                "AddressLine4": "",
                "Zip": "91304",
                "City": "Canoga Park"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "_index": "pulse",
          "_id": "7723",
          "_score": 10.891928,
          "_source": {
            "ProfileName": "ENCINO PHARMACY_AKA MDR PHARMACEUTICAL CARE",
            "State": "MI",
            "BusinessModel": "Dispenser",
            "LicenseInfo": [
              {
                "LicenseType": "PHARMACY",
                "LicenseNumber": "5301010993",
                "AddressLine1": "17071 VENTURA BLVD STE 100",
                "AddressLine2": "",
                "AddressLine3": "",
                "AddressLine4": "",
                "Zip": "91316",
                "City": "ENCINO"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "_index": "pulse",
          "_id": "7724",
          "_score": 9.796367,
          "_source": {
            "ProfileName": "Encino Pharmacy_aka Mdr Pharmaceutical Care",
            "State": "CA",
            "BusinessModel": "Dispenser",
            "LicenseInfo": [
              {
                "LicenseType": "Retail Pharmacy",
                "LicenseNumber": "34818",
                "AddressLine1": "17059-17071 VENTURA BLVD.",
                "AddressLine2": "STE. 100",
                "AddressLine3": "",
                "AddressLine4": "",
                "Zip": "91316",
                "City": "ENCINO"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "_index": "pulse",
          "_id": "192",
          "_score": 9.656487,
          "_source": {
            "ProfileName": "Abdin Pharmacies Pharma LLC",
            "State": "FL",
            "BusinessModel": "Dispenser",
            "LicenseInfo": [
              {
                "LicenseType": "Pharmacy",
                "LicenseNumber": "036936",
                "AddressLine1": "1873 SECOND AVE. NEW",
                "AddressLine2": "",
                "AddressLine3": "",
                "AddressLine4": "",
                "Zip": "10029",
                "City": "YORK"
              },
              {
                "LicenseType": "Pharmacy",
                "LicenseNumber": "033404",
                "AddressLine1": "1401 BRONX RIVER AVE.",
                "AddressLine2": "",
                "AddressLine3": "",
                "AddressLine4": "",
                "Zip": "10472",
                "City": "BRONX"
              },
              {
                "LicenseType": "Pharmacy",
                "LicenseNumber": "PH33043",
                "AddressLine1": "32866 US Hwy 19N",
                "AddressLine2": "",
                "AddressLine3": "",
                "AddressLine4": "",
                "Zip": "34684",
                "City": "PALM HARBOR"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "_index": "pulse",
          "_id": "17304",
          "_score": 9.186218,
          "_source": {
            "ProfileName": "PHARMALABS, LLC PharmaLabs",
            "State": "FL",
            "BusinessModel": "Dispenser",
            "LicenseInfo": [
              {
                "LicenseType": "Pharmacy",
                "LicenseNumber": "PH26495",
                "AddressLine1": "10901 ROOSEVELT BOULEVARD NORTH SUITE 1200",
                "AddressLine2": "",
                "AddressLine3": "",
                "AddressLine4": "",
                "Zip": "33716",
                "City": "Saint Petersburg"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f4dquv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-auto-active-first-option-example.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-auto-active-first-option-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-auto-active-first-option-example.css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following

```js
    var results={
          "hits": {
            "hits": [
              {
                "_source": {
                  "ProfileName": "",
                  "AddressLine1": [
                    "7508 abc 105",
                    "7400 def, Suite 200",
                    "727 xyz",
                    "8001 123",
                    "1650 ngr",
                  ],
                  "AddressLine2": [
                  "11333 East ",
                    "2308 North ",
                    "8831 East ",
                    "204 dsj",
                    "1517 HWY "
                ],
                  "AddressLine3": [],
                  "AddressLine4": [],
                  "Zip": [
                    "116-900",
                    "749-01",
                    "77-52",
                    "179",
                    "702",
                    "746",
                    "7402",
                    "74-5801",
                    "741",
                    "7342"
                  ],
                  "City": [
                    "OKLAHOMA CITY",
                    "Oklahoma City",
                    "OKLAHOMA CITY",
                    "OKLAHOMA CITY",
                    "Broken Arrow",
                    "Tulsa",
                    "BROKEN ARROW",
                    "TULSA",
                    "PRYOR",
                    "GUYMON"
                  ],
                  "State": "OK",
                  "LicenseType": "Wholesale Distributor",
                  "BusinessModel": "Wholesaler",
                  "LicenseNumber": [
                    "1-W-1",
                    "1-W-5",
                    "1-W-6",
                    "1-W-82",
                    "2-W-12",
                    "2-W-45",
                    "2-W-416",
                    "2-W-91",
                    "30-W-21",
                    "43-W-95"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "_source": {
                  "ProfileName": "HEALTHCARE ",
                  "AddressLine1": [
                    "110 Rsahasd"
                  ],
                  "AddressLine2": [
                    "220 road"
                  ],
                  "AddressLine3": [],
                  "AddressLine4": [],
                  "Zip": [
                    "73075"
                  ],
                  "City": [
                    "PAULS VALLEY"
                  ],
                  "State": "OK",
                  "LicenseType": "Retail",
                  "BusinessModel": "Dispenser",
                  "LicenseNumber": [
                    "2-667"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "_index": "pulse",
                "_id": "19297",
                "_score": 5.054507,
                "_source": {
                  "ProfileName": "PHARMACY",
                  "AddressLine1": [
                    "101 West MAIN",
                    "101 East MAIN"
                  ],
                  "AddressLine2": [],
                  "AddressLine3": [],
                  "AddressLine4": [],
                  "Zip": [
                    "749",
                    "739"
                  ],
                  "City": [
                    "JOHN",
                    "JON"
                  ],
                  "State": "OK",
                  "LicenseType": "Retail",
                  "BusinessModel": "Dispenser",
                  "LicenseNumber": [
                    "1-89",
                    "1-39"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "_index": "pulse",
                "_id": "22739",
                "_score": 5.054507,
                "_source": {
                  "ProfileName": "THE MEDICINE ",
                  "AddressLine1": [
                    "311 N WASHINGTON AVENUE",
                    "311 N WASHINGTON AVENUE"
                  ],
                  "AddressLine2": [],
                  "AddressLine3": [],
                  "AddressLine4": [],
                  "Zip": [
                    "74701-3641",
                    "74701-3641"
                  ],
                  "City": [
                    "DURANT",
                    "DURANT"
                  ],
                  "State": "OK",
                  "LicenseType": "Retail",
                  "BusinessModel": "Dispenser",
                  "LicenseNumber": [
                    "27-4393",
                    "27-8581"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "_index": "pulse",
                "_id": "27256",
                "_score": 5.054507,
                "_source": {
                  "ProfileName": "WAL-MART ",
                  "AddressLine1": [
                    "7520 East ",
                    "772 North",
                    "2705 West",
                    "1018 N ",
                    "3571 W ",
                    "2551 CLASS",
                    "13503 S ",
                    "3651 CLASS",
                    "3301 SW 104",
                    "4545 W 6TH"
                  ],
                  "AddressLine2": [
                  "6437 North",
                    "14185 drive",
                    "4900 Sooner",
                    "2001 SST",
                    "2019 EST",
                    "10938 SDR",
                    "12200 SWACO",
                    "12912 E N",
                    "3900 EHILLDR",
                    "3139 SE",
                    ],
                  "AddressLine3": [],
                  "AddressLine4": [],
                  "Zip": [
                    "63110",
                    "63132",
                    "63020",
                    "63135",
                    "63018",
                    "64137",
                    "64133",
                    "64033",
                    "64055",
                    "64014",
                  ],
                  "City": [
                    "MIDWEST CITY",
                    "WARR ACRES",
                    "CHOCTAW",
                    "OKLAHOMA CITY",
                    "CHICKASHA",
                    "TULSA",
                    "TULSA",
                    "GLENPOOL",
                    "OWASSO",
                    "BROKEN ARROW",
                  ],
                  "State": "OK",
                  "LicenseType": "Retail",
                  "BusinessModel": "Dispenser",
                  "LicenseNumber": [
                    "1-5770",
                    "1-6379",
                    "1-6621",
                    "1-6934",
                    "18-5060",
                    "2-3864",
                    "2-5116",
                    "2-5298",
                    "2-5444",
                    "2-5449",
                    "2-6632",
                    "26-6921",
                    "2-6710",
                    "2-7368",
                    "2-7447",
                    "29-3720",
                    "30-6922",
                    "34-4508",
                    "35-5557",
                    "3-6891",
                    "46-5049",
                    "52-5782",
                    "55-5459",
                    "5-6935",
                    "7-6284",
                    "7-6951",
                    "7-7474",
                    "7-7573",
                    "7-7692",
                    "8-5133"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        } ;
   
        var data=[];
        results.hits.hits.forEach(h=>{
        let item=h._source;
         let addressProps=Object.keys(item).filter(p=> p.startsWith('AddressLine') && item[p].length >0);
         
         addressProps.forEach(ap=>{
            let addresses=item[ap].map((ai,idx)=>{
             let address= `${ai} ${item.City[idx]} ${item.State} ${item.Zip[idx]}`;
             return {name:item.ProfileName,address}
            });
           data= data.concat(addresses);
         })
        });
       
     console.log(data);
```

Comment: thanks for response, i just gave an example how my data must come, it must be dynamically data binded, for example if i have 10 address strings under addressLine1, then all 10 must be appended with 10 states, 10 zips and profile names

Comment: @Bhrungarajni please add your expected output to the question I don't see any example data for output in the question

Comment: @Bhrungarajni check updated answer and if still don't meet your requirement then please add the exact sample output data that you need

Comment: is there any possible way where in i can get only License number as other array of object based on json data, pls help

Comment: @Bhrungarajni not sure what you need maybe post another question with the exact output required

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75946317/how-to-concat-all-license-number-into-one-array-using-angular15-and-javascript

Comment: hi jitender, now the json has changed in the formated i pasted in question as new JSON value, and i tried modifying in this way

Comment: hi jitender, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76107434/how-to-make-different-address-under-one-array-to-be-added-as-new-address-objects