# how to make different address under one array to be added as new address objects in angular15

Tags: javascript, angular

Hi i am working on angular15, here i have got json data like this and i have to bring data for address along with profileName, so my response should be like:

**Expected Result:**

```
[
{name:'Pharmarx Pharmaceutical Inc', address:'21441 Osborne St Ste C & D, Canoga Park, CA, 91304'},
{name:'Pharmarx Pharmaceutical Inc', address:'441 abc address, Canoga Park, CA, 91304'},
{name:'Pharmarx Pharmaceutical Inc', address:'231 osborne, Canoga Park, CA, 91304'},
{name:'Pharmarx Pharmaceutical Inc', address:'987 osborneOsborne St Ste C & D, Canoga Park, CA, 91304'}, 
{name:'ENCINO PHARMACY_AKA MDR PHARMACEUTICAL CARE', address:'17071 VENTURA BLVD STE 100 ECINO, MI,91316'}
]
```

Json:

```
{
  "took": 178,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 0,
    "successful": 0,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 10000,
      "relation": "gte"
    },
    "max_score": 12.9226,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "pulse",
        "_id": "17320",
        "_score": 12.9226,
        "_source": {
          "ProfileName": "Pharmarx Pharmaceutical Inc",
          "BusinessModel": "Dispenser",
          "LicenseInfo": [
            {
              "LicenseType": "Resident Licensed Sterile Compounding",
              "LicenseNumber": "99658",
              "AddressLine1": "21441 Osborne St Ste C & D",
              "AddressLine2": "441 abc address",
              "AddressLine3": "231 osborne",
              "AddressLine4": "",
              "Zip": "91304",
              "City": "Canoga Park",
              "State": "CA",
            },
            {
              "LicenseType": "Retail Pharmacy",
              "LicenseNumber": "50511",
              "AddressLine1": "21441 Osborne St Ste C & D",
              "AddressLine2": "987 osborne",
              "AddressLine3": "",
              "AddressLine4": "",
              "Zip": "91304",
              "City": "Canoga Park"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "pulse",
        "_id": "7723",
        "_score": 10.891928,
        "_source": {
          "ProfileName": "ENCINO PHARMACY_AKA MDR PHARMACEUTICAL CARE",
          "State": "MI",
          "BusinessModel": "Dispenser",
          "LicenseInfo": [
            {
              "LicenseType": "PHARMACY",
              "LicenseNumber": "5301010993",
              "AddressLine1": "17071 VENTURA BLVD STE 100",
              "AddressLine2": "",
              "AddressLine3": "",
              "AddressLine4": "",
              "Zip": "91316",
              "City": "ENCINO"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "pulse",
        "_id": "7724",
        "_score": 9.796367,
        "_source": {
          "ProfileName": "Encino Pharmacy_aka Mdr Pharmaceutical Care",
          "State": "CA",
          "BusinessModel": "Dispenser",
          "LicenseInfo": [
            {
              "LicenseType": "Retail Pharmacy",
              "LicenseNumber": "34818",
              "AddressLine1": "17059-17071 VENTURA BLVD.",
              "AddressLine2": "STE. 100",
              "AddressLine3": "",
              "AddressLine4": "",
              "Zip": "91316",
              "City": "ENCINO"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "pulse",
        "_id": "192",
        "_score": 9.656487,
        "_source": {
          "ProfileName": "Abdin Pharmacies Pharma LLC",
          "State": "FL",
          "BusinessModel": "Dispenser",
          "LicenseInfo": [
            {
              "LicenseType": "Pharmacy",
              "LicenseNumber": "036936",
              "AddressLine1": "1873 SECOND AVE. NEW",
              "AddressLine2": "",
              "AddressLine3": "",
              "AddressLine4": "",
              "Zip": "10029",
              "City": "YORK"
            },
            {
              "LicenseType": "Pharmacy",
              "LicenseNumber": "033404",
              "AddressLine1": "1401 BRONX RIVER AVE.",
              "AddressLine2": "",
              "AddressLine3": "",
              "AddressLine4": "",
              "Zip": "10472",
              "City": "BRONX"
            },
            {
              "LicenseType": "Pharmacy",
              "LicenseNumber": "PH33043",
              "AddressLine1": "32866 US Hwy 19N",
              "AddressLine2": "",
              "AddressLine3": "",
              "AddressLine4": "",
              "Zip": "34684",
              "City": "PALM HARBOR"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "pulse",
        "_id": "17304",
        "_score": 9.186218,
        "_source": {
          "ProfileName": "PHARMALABS, LLC PharmaLabs",
          "State": "FL",
          "BusinessModel": "Dispenser",
          "LicenseInfo": [
            {
              "LicenseType": "Pharmacy",
              "LicenseNumber": "PH26495",
              "AddressLine1": "10901 ROOSEVELT BOULEVARD NORTH SUITE 1200",
              "AddressLine2": "",
              "AddressLine3": "",
              "AddressLine4": "",
              "Zip": "33716",
              "City": "Saint Petersburg"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Ts:

```
 results = searchData.hits;
          if (results.hits.length > 0) {
            results.hits.forEach(h => {
              let item = h._source;
              item.LicenseInfo.forEach(ap => {
                let address = `${ap.AddressLine1} ${ap.AddressLine2} ${ap.AddressLine3} ${ap.AddressLine4} ${ap.City} ${item.State} ${ap.Zip}`;
                let addresses = { name: item.ProfileName, address }
                data = data.concat(addresses);
              })
              this.seeResultsData = data;
              return data;
            })
            return null;
          }
```

now, i am getting this.seeResultsData as
**Currently i am getting:**

```
[
{name:'Pharmarx Pharmaceutical Inc', address:'21441 Osborne St Ste C & D 441 abc address 231 osborne 987 osborneOsborne St Ste C & D, Canoga Park, CA, 91304'},
{name:'ENCINO PHARMACY_AKA MDR PHARMACEUTICAL CARE', address:'17071 VENTURA BLVD STE 100 ECINO, MI,91316'}
]
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i want to get data as 1st array of object i had given example like that

Comment: like for each address, i need one object to be created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get all the adresses, you could try something like this:

```
const result:{ name:string, adress:string }[] = [];
searchData.hits.hits.foreach(hit=>{
 const source = hit._source;
 const name = source.ProfileName;
 source.LicenseInfo.foreach(license=>{
   const adresseKeys = Object.keys(licence).filter(key => key.startsWith('AddressLine'));
   adresseKeys.foreach(key=>{
     if(!!licence[key]){ 
       const adress = `${licence[key]}, ${licence.City}, ${source.State}, ${licence.Zip}`
       // Avoid duplication
       if(!result.some(item => item.name === name && item.adress = adress){
          result.push({name, adress}) 
       }       
   })
 })
})

this.seeResultsData = result;
```

Comment: thanks for response, can this be made dynamically instead of mentioning AddressLine1,AddressLine2 like that, because in future it may get add up also

Comment: Yes I have updated the answer, to get all the adress wich contains 'AdressLine'. I haven't tested the code, so there is probably some typo.

Comment: ya thanks for response, but city, state and zip has not got added

Comment: Should be fine now.

Comment: yes working as expected, perfect thanks

Comment: Why it is returning 12 objects and 5 address for the 'Pharmarx Pharmaceutical Inc'?

Comment: Indeed, there is some duplicated. It could be easily removed with a if statement

Comment: @Wandrille one help pls, here is there anyway to remove duplicate records from array of objects?

Comment: The code is updated

Comment: hi @Wandrille, can you please check this question,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76217665/how-to-show-parent-child-relation-using-treedata-in-angular15-using-ag-grid

Answer (score 0):

```
this.source.hits.hits.forEach((obj: any) => {
  obj._source.LicenseInfo.forEach((subObj:any) => {
    this.address.push({
      name: obj._source.ProfileName,
      address: `${subObj.AddressLine1}, ${subObj.AddressLine2}, ${subObj.AddressLine3}, ${subObj.AddressLine4}, ${subObj.City}, ${subObj.State}, ${subObj.Zip}`
    })
  });
});
```

**output**

```
[
  {
    "name": "Pharmarx Pharmaceutical Inc",
    "address": "21441 Osborne St Ste C & D, 441 abc address, 231 osborne, , Canoga Park, CA, 91304"
  },
  {
    "name": "Pharmarx Pharmaceutical Inc",
    "address": "21441 Osborne St Ste C & D, 987 osborne, , , Canoga Park, undefined, 91304"
  },
  {
    "name": "ENCINO PHARMACY_AKA MDR PHARMACEUTICAL CARE",
    "address": "17071 VENTURA BLVD STE 100, , , , ENCINO, undefined, 91316"
  },
  {
    "name": "Encino Pharmacy_aka Mdr Pharmaceutical Care",
    "address": "17059-17071 VENTURA BLVD., STE. 100, , , ENCINO, undefined, 91316"
  },
  {
    "name": "Abdin Pharmacies Pharma LLC",
    "address": "1873 SECOND AVE. NEW, , , , YORK, undefined, 10029"
  },
  {
    "name": "Abdin Pharmacies Pharma LLC",
    "address": "1401 BRONX RIVER AVE., , , , BRONX, undefined, 10472"
  },
  {
    "name": "Abdin Pharmacies Pharma LLC",
    "address": "32866 US Hwy 19N, , , , PALM HARBOR, undefined, 34684"
  },
  {
    "name": "PHARMALABS, LLC PharmaLabs",
    "address": "10901 ROOSEVELT BOULEVARD NORTH SUITE 1200, , , , Saint Petersburg, undefined, 33716"
  }
]
```

Comment: thanks for response, but my expected result is different

Comment: Under LicenseInfo there are multiple objects. Are you looking for the first object only?